# Dutch Citizenship - grandparents are Dutch

Tags: canada, citizenship, canadian-citizens, dutch-citizens

My maternal grandparents were born in the Netherlands and immigrated to Canada in the late 1950s. They were landed immigrants and never got their Canadian citizenship. My mother was born in Canada in 1962

For further information, my father is the child of two Dutch born parents who gained Canadian citizenship in a the 1950s. My father was born in Canada in 1956.

Are either of my parents entitled to Dutch Citizenship? And am I, as their daughter, eligible to apply for citizenship through my parents? Or would I have to become a citizen through naturalization?

Comment: "they are dual citizens of Canada and the Netherlands": how did they manage that?  Naturalization in a foreign country normally causes loss of Dutch nationality.  There are some exceptions -- which applied to them?   Dual nationals living outside the kingdom and outside the EU normally lose their Dutch nationality after 10 years, though the details have changed a few times and again there are exceptions. When was the last time they had a Dutch passport issued?  How old are you?

Comment: (Footnote to my previous comment: a recent change in the "ten year rule," as I've been calling it, is that the period has been extended to thirteen years.  I'll have to find a new name for it.  But this change went into effect a few months ago, so it won't have any impact on your situation unless you had a ten-year period expiring in the last few months.  This will commonly occur on your 28th birthday, but it could happen later if your circumstances triggered one of the exceptions until ten years ago, and it's only relevant if you were indeed Dutch from birth.)

Comment: Related question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/ancestry-visa-for-holland

Comment: @phoog. Thank you for your comment! My paternal grandparent were not dual citizens, I was told that by my dad, but I spoke with my grandmother and like you mentioned they gave up their Dutch nationality when then became Canadian citizens. 
 
Also, as for my age, I was born in 1985, so that would be beyond the thirteen year rule. 

Again, thanks for the info. Definitely happy to know :)

Comment: One of the exceptions of the 10-year rule is that it doesn't apply to minors. If you were Dutch at birth and none of the other exceptions applied to you, then you would have lost your Dutch nationality on your birthday in 2013 -- except the rule changed again in 2003, so if that happened after your birthday then you would have lost your Dutch nationality on the 10th anniversary of the change. But you really ought to look at the exceptions. You may also qualify as so-called "latent" Dutch. How old were your father's parents when they naturalized? Was it before or after his birth?

Comment: When did your parents marry? Did either of them ever live outside Canada? Did you? Did they or you ever work for the UN or a similar intergovernmental organization? Were you born before or after April 1st (when the 2003 changes to the current nationality law took effect)?  You might consider applying for a letter attesting to your Dutch nationality.  If it is refused then you would at least know precisely when your mother lost hers, or, if she somehow retained it, when you lost yours.